# Adding ObjectPropety for an Ontclass using Jena API

Tags: jena, owl

I intend to add object properties to classes using Jena API.

I can't find a proper way how to do this. I would like to achieve something similar to what can be done in Protege:
[image: ObjectProperty in Protege]

ExampleObjectProperty is my own ObjectProperty.

I tried adding this property using ontClass.addProperty, also adding a new statement to ontModel, but the result wasn't the same.

As far as I know, in Protege, blank node is generated (saying that :blank_node has some onProperty ExampleObjectProperty and ExampleClass has someValuesOf :blank_node... I'm not sure about this though).

Comment: Object properties cannot be "added" to classes directly. You have to declare an axiom. For instance in your case you've asserted that `ExampleResource` is a subclass of the expression `ExampleObjectProperty some ExampleClass`. You can look for ways to add axioms in Jena and how to use existential restrictions (the `some` keyword) to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[loopasam's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305302/loopasam) is correct;  you're not trying to "add a property to a class" or anything like that.  What you're trying to do is add a subclass axiom.  In the Manchester OWL syntax, it would look more or less like:

> ExampleResource **subClassOf** (ExampleObjectProperty **some** ExampleClass)

Jena's OntModel API makes it pretty easy to create that kind of axiom though.  Here's how you can do it:

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntProperty;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class SubclassOfRestriction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String NS = "https://stackoverflow.com/q/20476826/";
        final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM );

        // Create the two classes and the property that we'll use.
        final OntClass ec = model.createClass( NS+"ExampleClass" );
        final OntClass er = model.createClass( NS+"ExampleResource" );
        final OntProperty eop = model.createOntProperty( NS+"ExampleObjectProperty" );

        // addSuperClass and createSomeValuesFromRestriction should be pretty straight-
        // forward, especially if you look at the argument names in the Javadoc.  The 
        // null just indicates that the restriction class will be anonymous;  it doesn't
        // have an URI of its own.  
        er.addSuperClass( model.createSomeValuesFromRestriction( null, eop, ec ));

        // Write the model. 
        model.write( System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
        model.write( System.out, "TTL" );
    }
}
```

The output is:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Class rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/q/20476826/ExampleResource">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:someValuesFrom>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/q/20476826/ExampleClass"/>
        </owl:someValuesFrom>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <rdf:Property rdf:about="https://stackoverflow.com/q/20476826/ExampleObjectProperty"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

```
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<https://stackoverflow.com/q/20476826/ExampleObjectProperty>
        a       rdf:Property .

<https://stackoverflow.com/q/20476826/ExampleClass>
        a       owl:Class .

<https://stackoverflow.com/q/20476826/ExampleResource>
        a                owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a                   owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:onProperty      <https://stackoverflow.com/q/20476826/ExampleObjectProperty> ;
                           owl:someValuesFrom  <https://stackoverflow.com/q/20476826/ExampleClass>
                         ] .
```

In Protégé that appears as follows:

[image: Protégé screenshot similar to OP's]
                             ] .